# Eclipse exclude php files from validation but not build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have a very simple use case. Eclipse Kepler with PDF. New project with PHP nature.

One file at the root

```
# test.php
<?php

$fu = new Fu();
$fu->bar();

&
```

One file in a directory

```
# vendor/vendor.php
<?php

class Fu {
    public function bar () {

    }
}

&
```

Both files show an error in the Problems view. I need to exclude all files under vendor/ (recursively) from the Problems view, while keeping the code completion on objects defined under vendor/ (recursively).

Desired result:

- code completion in test.php still works on Fu and all classes defined under vendor/
- the Problems view doesn't show any error or warning on files under vendor/
- the Problems view shows errors and warnings on other files as usual
- the Problems view doesn't depend on the selected element

What I tried:

- removing vendor/ from the Build Path also removes all code completion on classes under vendor/
- Project > Properties > Validation > Enable project specific settings + PHP CodeSniffer Validator settings > Exclude Group > Folder: vendor doesn't do anything at all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should install latest PDT (3.3.1 is available on marketplace) into your eclipse kepler instance.

This version have special feature: "library dir". This functionality allow you to disable all validators (JS/PHP/HTML/CSS...) on buildpath dir.

Comment: Wonderful. I just had to right-click on the vendor folder and select "Use as Library Folder".

Comment: I've been chasing this for 4 years.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a little update. In Oxygen (4.7) right click on a folder and choose "Use As Library Folder".

Comment: Thank you very much, BTW this should be noted in the [official docs](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/adding_a_php_library.htm) **"This functionality allow you to disable all validators (JS/PHP/HTML/CSS...) on buildpath dir."** . I'v been looking for this feature for a long time

Comment: Help from this address is here due historical reasons. Latest help is available at http://help.eclipse.org/photon. Anyway it's a little bit outdated ;)